# Why in spite of having private constructor, it uses SEALED in the class in MSDN

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, singleton

I am just learning about Singleton to deepen my knowledge on this.

I have come across MSDN that it uses SEALED and claiming that we can not derive further and hence can not create an instance of the dervied when our aim is singleton. I agree.

However, I see that already a private constructor is there to prevent derivation, as when I tried it in VS, it says inaccessible due to protection level, fair enough. So I feel this itself solves the purpose of disallowing derivation. Why Sealed? Why especially in the document, they wrote it that Sealed is used to achieve this when they didn't say anything about private constructor for this purpose?

I am really curious as I am in learning curve. Please help.

This is what MSDN article has:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

   private Singleton(){}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         return instance; 
      }
   }
}
```

And the website I am referring to is this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you used a nested class you could inherit from the parent class and provide a public constructor like this...

```
public class Parent 
{
    private Parent(){}

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public Child() {}
    }
}
```

Now you can do this...

```
var child = new Parent.Child();
```

That breaks the Singleton pattern. Adding the `sealed` modifier prevents this.

Comment: Shoe, thank you very much, fair enough, but why would I even code a subclass in a class which implements Singleton? Is there any real-time scenario where I can benefit from such coding style? Otherwise I completely agree with you. Please help me, just curious and making a positive discussion :)

Comment: You probably wouldn't, but the developer that you are working with might because he doesn't understand why he shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you :) One small question; why they use readonly here? Although I know the meaning of readonly but couldn't understand why they want to use it here or is it that we can not achieve singleton using same code without using readonly here?

Comment: readonly prevents the instance from getting reassigned from anywhere within the class itself, except from within a static constructor.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee: Mate, there is no static constructor here. To help you understand my question, when I removed READONLY, still it behaves same. Why readonly here?

Comment: Due to "STATIC" it already instantiate only once but why READONLY? Can you not see the difference removing readonly also behaves in same way?

Comment: Lets say you wrote a method inside your singleton class called `DoStuff()`. By using `readonly` it prevents you from assigning to the `instance` field within that method, e.g. making new singleton instances whenever you want.

Comment: @Deevinee: "static" makes the reference "instance" belong to the Singleton class, i.e., it does not belong to any Singleton object. But "static" does not restrict the "instance" reference from getting reassigned. You might also want to google "static constructor".